Variables aren't initialized as expected
I have a persistent question that I haven't found an answer to yet. Why is the last variable in example 1 not initialized with the value that was entered, while in example 2 this is the case?
EXAMPLE 1:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float a, b, c, average = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    average = (a * 2 + b * 3 + c * 5) / 10;

    printf("AVERAGE = %.1f\n", average);

    return 0;
}

EXAMPLE 2:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float a, b, c = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    float average = (a * 2 + b * 3 + c * 5) / 10;

    printf("AVERAGE = %.1f\n", average);

    return 0;
}

I tried assigning three prompt-typed values to the variables in example 2, but the last variable always stores an incorrect value. This changes when I declare a fourth variable -- average -- on the same line without assigning a value to it.

I don't think scanf returns what you think it does: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

This is very odd. You're assigning the int-typed result of scanf (which tells you how many values from your format string were filled in) to float average. I'm not sure if it's even legal to reference variables in their initializer like this.

@Alexander it is

This line:
float a, b, c = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

Is equivalent to these lines:
float a;
float b;
float c;
int result;
result = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
c = result;

(Except that it doesn't actually declare a variable named result.)
I recommend you don't mix variable declarations with scanf() on a single line. See the answer from gulpr for how to do this properly.

Why assign scanf results to average? scanf returns number of successfull assignments.
Write your code like:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float a, b, c, average;

    int n = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
    if (n == EOF) {
        printf("end of file!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (n != 3) {
        printf("expected 3 numbers, but read %d!\n", n);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    average = (a * 2 + b * 3 + c * 5) / 10;
    printf("AVERAGE = %.1f\n", average);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

in detail, scanf result is:

Number of assignments
EOF if an error accured (if Contrl-D in Unix or Control-Z in windows pressed)


if scanf fails it will invoke UB

I updated the code for error checking

Check if scanf succeeded. It returns the number of successfully scanned items.
int main(){
    double a, b, c, average;
    int result  = scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c);

    if(result == 3)
    {
        average = (a * 2 + b * 3 + c * 5) / 10;
        printf("a = %f,  b = %f, c = %f, AVERAGE = %.1f\n", a, b, c, average);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("scanf error\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

https://godbolt.org/z/coav7zva7

I tried assigning three prompt-typed values to the variables in
example 2, but the last variable always stores an incorrect value.
This changes when I declare a fourth variable -- average -- on the
same line without assigning a value to it.

c = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c); This line will assign c the number of successfully scanned parameters or with EOF converted to float if I/O error occurred
